# jQuery. Вывести текст, что находится в теге, в консоль

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть некий родительский блок div. В нем две кнопки с одинаковыми класами, но разные значения в data-*. В зависимости, на какую кнопку клацнули, нужно достать текст в самом теге(Fade out или же Fade in) и именно это вывести в консоль

Вот код

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<div class='div'>
<button class="btn1" data-bq="1">Fade out</button>
<button class="btn1" data-bq="2">Fade in</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".div").click(function(evt){
      let targ = evt.target.dataset.bq
      console.log(targ)
  
      $("p").fadeOut();
    
      if(targ === "1"){
       $(".btn1").addClass("mytry")
       console.log($(".mytry").text())
      } else if (targ === "2") {
       $('.btn1').addClass("twe")
       console.log($(".twe").text())
      }   
    })
  });
```

добилась только того что выводит значение атрибута нажатой кнопки, теперь бы именно текст с этой кнопки вывести в консоль. Не знаю как написать, что типа: ми нажали на кнопку, узнали какой у нее атрибут, потом в зависимости от атрибута напялили доп класс, потом находим этот доп класс и именно по нему достаем текст...но что-то не выходит..не знаю что использовать( пару дней как начала разбираться в jquery

Заранее благодарю за любую помощь

Comment: а зачем так сложно? у вас уже имеется класс btn на кнопках, ловим событие нажатия, this внутри уже будет ссылаться на текущий элемент, с ним и делайте что хотите: вот примерно >> https://codepen.io/damonhaswell/pen/MWQrxKb?editors=1111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Делегирование события](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation) в обработчике [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/), где по триггеру по элементу `[data-bq]` выводим его текст, методом [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/)

```js
$('.div').on('click', '[data-bq]', function() { // Делегируем событие, при нажатии на какой-то элемент с атрибутом `data-bq` внутри элемента `.div`, запустим следующий код:
  console.info($(this).text()); // покажим текст нажатого элемента
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='div'>
  <button class="btn1" data-bq="1">Fade out</button>
  <button class="btn1" data-bq="2">Fade in</button>
</div>
```